# RApply function is ouputting Zeroes

Tags: r

I want to apply a rolling function to a data set but I am getting the wrong output using rollapply. I provided a dataset you can test.

Here is my dataset:

```
library(zoo)
source('k.r')

set.seed(2)
data<-runif(60, min= 1, max= 4) ########this is my data
cbind(data)
#this is a call to rollapply and my "k" function
k<-rollapply(data, 21, FUN="k")
k


################here is my "k" function
k<- function(data)
{
  minData<-min(data)
  maxData<-max(data)
  value <-   ( data[length(data)]- minData)/(maxData - minData)    * 100
}
```

The output of k is below and my question is why are there 2 "0" elements and a "100" element. When I paste the value of the data vector in excel and perform this calcualtion I do not get 0 or 100.

As a double check if you paste the values of cbind(data) into excel you can use this formula to see that there should not be "0" or "100":
=(B22-MIN(B2:B21))/(MAX(B2:B21)-MIN(B2:B21))*100

```
65.1105969
34.6753392
84.5233679
8.378125
30.2071295
45.9047099
8.2389469
31.2932327
98.4741346
6.3669142
0
15.9658672
82.7940886
88.8675737
52.1610354
63.8501035
87.5854463
28.8224679
68.9761351
14.7081374
100
29.5060511
10.7760849
15.7298722
96.120093
80.7617139
99.2752118
34.8676243
50.6072898
82.3609341
0
0.7782399
69.3906549
94.6637968
27.5279067
82.57081
79.9050722
100
61.80975
71.6114912
```

Any ideas why rollapply is returing "0" and "100"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The excel formula excludes `data[length(datea)]` in the calculation of the min and max but the function `k` includes it.